# Connect to staging vpn using openvpen instead of openvpn3

Tags: linux, vpn, linux-mint, openvpn

I was given the following files from work, in a compressed folder

> ca.crt
> dh.pem
> myuser.crt
> myuser.key
> myuser.ovpn
> ta.key

The suggested way is to connect using openvpn3 from [this site](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN3Linux)

Is it possible to use these files to connect using the command line openvpn that comes with the linux mint distribution?

Thank you

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux tools/apps. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this OpenVPN config for openvpn2. Just install Linux Mint `openvpn` package

```
apt update 
apt install openvpn
```

and try to connect

```
openvpn --config <path to>/myuser.ovpn
```

ALso check if this lines exists in `myuser.ovpn`

```
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
script-security 2
```

Comment: No, it doesn't have any of those. And the file name is myuser.ovpn I misstyped it in the question

Comment: Append this line to the end of `myuser.ovpn` and try to connect

Comment: I get ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1). It may also be that the files that I was sent are not for linux.

Comment: Use `sudo openvpn --config <path to>/myuser.ovpn`

Comment: Yeah, thank you @ExploitFate, it worked. Question is closed so I cannot accept a comment